# Can ssl folder be removed without causing conflict

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, certificates

In `/etc/httpd` the `ssl` folder, if that is removed does that mean any site on the server if directed to `https://` will not throw warning?

I got a certificate a while back but soon realized if not a paid certificate would be useless for visitors to site because a pop up would warn them of the site being untrusted.

Now I simply want to remove it and am wondering if this `ssl` folder is the one to delete or if I must do other steps to ensure I've reversed the process of a "free" certificate. I'd rather have none at all than a bogus one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will depend on what you keep in that folder. Is it the certificates, or is it the httpd config for the SSL-enabled domain(s)?

What you need to do is to remove all SSL-related configuration from your httpd.conf and any virtual host config files. You also need to make sure that your server doesn't listen on port 443.

**Edit** Do this by editing your httpd.conf and look for the line that starts with

```
Listen
```

That line will contain the port numbers that the server listens on - remove 443 from the line. (More information about the format for that line is found at [the apache documentation site](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen).)

Once that is done, if people try to surf to your site using HTTPS, they will get an error message saying "Connection refused" - which means that your server doesn't accept any SSL traffic.

Comment: Brilliant- I think you have answered my question. :)

Comment: apache.crt  apache.key that is what is in that folder

Comment: In that case, removing only those files will mean that apache won't start at all - so not really what you want :-)

Comment: how do I make sure doesn't listen on port 443?

Comment: OH! haha Ok I will not do that

Comment: I added info about making it not listen to port 443.

Comment: I have had a break from all things computer and linux so need to revisit this sorry but thanks - I will go through your check list.

Comment: Don't forget to make backups of your config file before you start editing them, in case you make a mistake... it's saved me more than once!

Comment: I ran into problems finding the info in ssl.conf